# Where to find documentation on Swift type methods/functions

Tags: ios, swift, function, documentation, standards

I am new to Swift/iOS development and having trouble finding certain documentation. It must be out there somewhere if anyone is able to figure this stuff out. I just haven't been able to find it - my Google Fu isn't quite strong enough, I'm afraid.

Here is what I mean. I found instructions on writing a string to file using the write() function that is part of Swift's String type/structure (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string). In the instructions, a parameter called "atomically" is passed into the function. I cannot find any documentation stating exactly what that "atomically" parameter controls. I thought Apple would have something somewhere, but haven't found it. I also command+clicked on the function in Xcode and selected "Jump to Definition" to no avail. The best info I could find was by command-clicking and selecting "Show Quick Help."

Is there any more detailed source of information from Apple than https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string, or a better way to find things like which parameters are accepted by a function in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: You're entirely right to be confused, the bridging from ObjC/Foundation types into Swift is implicit, mystical black magic

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I think you mixed something up. You are probably talking about the (deprecated) `.write()` method of `NSString`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1497362-write
NSString is the legacy version of String used by ObjectiveC and still around in Swift to be interoperable with ObjC

It's easy with swift to stumble upon outdated tutorials because the language changed a lot in the last years. Articles you find from 3-4 years ago might already include outdated information.

The current way to write any data to a file is `.write()` on the `Data` struct: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779858-write